# Problema Librería ZXingScannerView Android

Tags: android

Tengo un problema con la librería `ZXingScannerView`, me bloquea los botones que se encuentran en la clase donde hago el llamado a ella.

```
public class MainActivity_lector extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lector);
    }

    public void onClick2(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main_estadisticas.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }
```

La Función `OnClick2` es bloqueada por la librería.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Scan QR Code"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="ver estadísticas"
    android:onClick="onClick2"/>
```

me doy cuenta que es la librería debido a que quito los implements que hacen el llamado al contenido de la librería de la clase principal, el botón empieza a funcionar, pero el lector ya deja de hacerlo

Comment: Como sabes que es la librería la que te bloquea los botones?

Comment: Si en verdad lo bloquea la librería porque se sobreescribe, cambia el nombre del método.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas definiendo recibir una vista como parametro en ambos métodos, esto significa que estas usando el metodo `android:onClick` en las vistas.

Dentro del archivo `activity_lector.xml` deben encontrarse estas vistas y tener definidos los métodos:

```
android:onClick=onClick
```

y

```
android:onClick=onClick2
```

> La Función OnClick2 es bloqueada por la librería.

Si el método `onClick2` no se esta llamando porque se esta sobreescribiendo  puedes optar por cambiar el nombre del método en el layout y en tu código.

Comment: muchas gracias por la guía, pero al hacer el cambio que sugieres el problema persiste

realice este cambio:

android:onClick="verEstadisticas"

Comment: Revisa el LogCat porque me parece que es otro problema. Main_estadisticas extiende de Activity?